# sqlite database connection: java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc, database-connection

Let me first start by saying that I am a total beginner to coding. I've studied java for only the last several few of high school, so don't be afraid of an overly simplified explanation.

I'm trying to create and connect a sqlite database using BlueJ as my IDE. I don't really understand what I'm doing, but I followed some instructions on youtube. Anyway, when I run the program I get a "java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC." I've done several google searches, but most of the solutions refer to a misplaced jar file. They say "make sure the package is in the classpath," and I did that...atleast I think I did. It's in the java>extensions folder in BlueJ. Please let me know what's wrong with syntax or whatever the problem could be. If you need more information feel free to ask!

Help much appreciated,
Thanks!

Here's my code:

import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class javaconnect2
     {

```
     public static Connection ConnecrDB()

     {
         Connection conn = null;

         try

         {

             Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

             Connection conn =      DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/Users/aaronyih/Desktop/TEA/LearningGUI/TEA   DATABASE.sqlite");

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Established!");

             return(conn);

         }

         catch(Exception e)

         {

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

             return(null);

         }

     }
 }
```

Comment: *"They say "make sure the package is in the classpath," and I did that...atleast I think I did"* ... no, you didn't. Because that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your application's runtime classpath does not have the SQLLite driver jar. Keep it there and thy code shall execute.